# Selenium IE webdriver - how to cope when the application closes the browser window and launches a new one?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an instance where user try to log-in application (simple webpage). After successful log in, the application closes the current page and open a new webpage. Rest of the business operations start from there.

Till the point API clicks log-in button, everything goes fine. After log in (once the log in webpage closes and a new session gets opened), the API throws "**Unable to find browser**". This is true as the original driver instance has been closed by the application.

Is there a way to achieve these kind of scenarios using selenium, as they are very common now-a days in a typical business application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to driver a different browser window or iframe, you need to use `switchto`. From the [WebDriver faq](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_handle_pop_up_windows?):

> Q: How do I handle pop up windows?
>
> A: WebDriver offers the ability to cope with multiple windows. This is done by using the "WebDriver.switchTo().window()" method to switch to a window with a known name. If the name is not known, you can use "WebDriver.getWindowHandles()" to obtain a list of known windows. You may pass the handle to "switchTo().window()".

Comment: You can also use switchTo to get into an iFrame but you may need to remember to switch back out of the iFrame if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the Answer.
I did the below to achieve my query.

Execute a javascript to open a new window.

---

`IJavaScriptExecutor jScript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor; 
jScript.ExecuteScript("window.open()");`

---

Switch to the newly opened window.

---

`List<string> handles = driver.WindowHandles.ToList<string>();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(handles.Last());`

---

Start the Navigate and Login operation on the new window

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Your website");
```

**After login, the application will close the new window but the main driver window will still be alive.**

Implement a simple SwitchTo() for the new window to start new business operations

```
List<string> handles = driver.WindowHandles.ToList<string>();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(handles.Last());
```